# How to make this code work?

Tags: php

I'm having a little problem, I guess it is from here:

```
if($thepage == "") {
    $strSQL = "SELECT * FROM Banlist LIMIT 0 , 15";
}
if($thepage == 2) {
    $strSQL = "SELECT * FROM Banlist LIMIT 15 , 30";
}
if($thepage == 3) {
    $strSQL = "SELECT * FROM Banlist LIMIT 30 , 45";
}
if($thepage == 4) {
    $strSQL = "SELECT * FROM Banlist LIMIT 45, 60";
}
if($thepage == 5) {
    $strSQL = "SELECT * FROM Banlist LIMIT 60 , 75";
}
if($thepage == 6) {
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM Banlist LIMIT 75 , 90";
}
if($thepage == 7) {
    $strSQL = "SELECT * FROM Banlist LIMIT 90 , 105";
}
if($thepage == 8) {
    $strSQL = "SELECT * FROM Banlist LIMIT 105 , 120";
}
```

In my browser, before the HTML part of the PHP code it shows me this:

```
} } } } } } } } } } } } } } }
```

What seems to be the problem?

PS: I want to make a little code that makes me a page browser like this:

```
(page: 1  2  3  4  5 ... LAST)
```

Comment: Use a `switch` statement for this kind of test. http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

Comment: It would be helpful to post the rest of your code, as this doesn;t really show us much.  Nothing wrong with the code as far as I can see, so must be something somewhere else int he code.

Comment: Me, I am a oracle and I guess the problem derives from elsewhere. BTW: try out [a switch](http://php.net/control-structures.switch.php).

Comment: I guess you want to show 15 results per page, so please keep it as LIMIT X, Y (Y is always 15, only change X as per your page number.) See my comment.

Comment: First, right click your page and hit "View Source" and double-check that your PHP isn't being displayed on the page. The issue with the }s is quite odd. I suspect that it is caused by code elsewhere however it could be the result of an incorrectly configured server and a confused browser.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php
if(!isset($thepage) || ( $thepage==1 )) {
   $startLimit = 0;
} else {
   $startLimit = 15 * $thepage;
}

$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM Banlist LIMIT " . $startLimit . " , 15";
?>
```

Short and simple.

Comment: That would mean that page 1 starts from item 15 though

Answer (score 1):

You could clean it uop a little like this, then you wouldn't need the if.

```
$limitLength = 15;
$thepage = $thepage == ""? 1: $thepage;
$baseLimit = ($thepage-1) * $limitLength;
$strSQL = sprintf("SELECT * FROM BanList LIMIT %d, %d", $baseLimit, $limitLength;
```

But we'd need to see the whole page to see where those braces are coming from

Answer (score 0):

```
$ENTRIES_PER_PAGE = 15;

$strSQL = 'SELECT * FROM banlist LIMIT '.($ENTRIES_PER_PAGE * (empty($thepage)? 0 : $thepage - 1)).', '.$ENTRIES_PER_PAGE;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some problems with your code…

If you want to use "if" instead of case, you should use "elsif"… as, even if the first check is the right one, you use server time to check the rest…

I think it would be easier to maintain something like this:

```
$top = $thepage ? ($thepage - 1) * 15 : 0;
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM Banlist LIMIT  $top, 15";
```

EDIT: corrected the code according to comment :P

Comment: You're $bottom is specifying the top record to get, when the syntax actually requires the number of records to get, so always 15